# How to change Main method to async in new .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, asynchronous, console-application, .net-6.0, main-method

I would like to change `Main` method to `async`, but I don't know how to edit this method, since it is "invisible" in .NET 6.0.
I want it to look something like this: `static async Task Main(string[] args)`. So how can I edit it?

Comment: It's only 'invisible' if you choose to use C# that way.  You can still create a namespace/class/main if you want to.

Answer (score 24):

If you want to stick with top-level statements, you don't need to change anything. Just use `await` within your top-level statements, and the compiler will generate an async method for you.

If you'd prefer to write your own class declaration, that's absolutely fine. So for example, this is fine:

```cs
await Task.Delay(1000);
Console.WriteLine($"Hi {args[0]}");
```

... and so is this:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine($"Hi {args[0]}");
    }
}
```